# Can I set the focal length of iphone camera programmatically?

Tags: iphone, camera

Hey therer, I am wondering whether I could fix the focal length of iPhone camera to certain distance, such as 120mm. Is it possible to achieve this programmatically?

Thank you for your time and help :D

Answer (score 8):

No, the iPhone camera is fixed focal length ([5.4mm for the iPhone 4](http://falklumo.blogspot.com/2010/06/apple-iphone-4-camera-specs.html)) and cannot zoom - perhaps you mean [focal distance](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/forums/thread2456.htm) which is the distance from the lens at which an image is in focus?  If you mean focal distance, then this answer is of no use to you. :-(

If you want to *simulate* the effect of different focal length (i.e. zoom), you can simply crop the image, although your cropped image will be of lower resolution than the uncropped original.

The iPhone 4 has a real focal length of 5.4mm, and a full-frame equivalent focal length of 29.4mm.  Your desired 120mm focal length is also full-frame equivalent.

120/29.4 is about 4.  So crop out the middle 1/4 (25%) of the height and width of the iPhone photo using your application, and you have simulated the Field of View of a 120mm lens.

The iPhone 4 takes photos at 2592x1936, so the cropped photo will be 648x484.  That's approximately VGA resolution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply. Yes you are right. Focal distance is the one I am looking for. Do you know how to fix the focal distance? Thank you again for your reply :D

Comment: sorry, don't know how to set the focal distance.